# What is the Python equivalent to C# LINQ Sum()

Tags: c#, python

In C# I can get the sum of some values like so:

```
new List<Tuple<string, int>>().Sum(x => x.Item2);
```

How can I achieve the same result in Python? Assuming I have a list of tuples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent is a [comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) inside a [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

```
sum(x[1] for x in tuples)
```

For example, we can define some sample random data.

```
from random import randint

r = lambda: randint(0, 100)

data = [(r(), r(), r()) for x in range(100)]

sum(x[1] for x in data)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's a generator expression.

Comment: All works. It's pretty clean syntax. I was about to start looping the collection manually and adding x[1]th elements up.